# Groovy pop min from array

Tags: arrays, groovy, soapui, min

I need to find the minimum value of an array then remove it.

How can I use `min()` and `pop()` in one statement ?

So I have five files, number (1,2,3,4,5) in a loop. 
After processing the first file, I need to remove it.

When I do pop alone, it picks up file number 5 and drops it and then process next file 4, and so on.

I need to reverse the order which the files are being processed:

```
 def fileName = fileList.pop()
 def testCaseName = fileName[0..-5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `pop()` the list elements if you want to loop the list in order why you don't use `each`  to iterate the list in desired order:

```
fileList.each{ fileName ->
     def testCaseName = fileName[0..-5]
     ...
}
```

Or if you can not use `each` and you need to have the remaining elements in a list you can use `reverse()` before start `pop()`ing elements:

```
fileList = fileList.reverse()
def fileName = fileList.pop()
def testCaseName = fileName[0..-5]
...
```